# Visual Composer fatal error during activation

Tags: wordpress, plugins, visual-composer

Our website was working fine, suddenly the server give an fatal error. When investigation it seems Visual Composer is throwing an error. We deactivate VC and that brought the site back without images or styling. When trying to activate Visual Composer it gives the following error.

```
Warning: require_once(/www/wp-content/plugins/visualcomposer/visualcomposer/Env.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/wp-content/plugins/visualcomposer/plugin-wordpress.php on line 102 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/www/wp-content/plugins/visualcomposer/visualcomposer/Env.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /www/wp-content/plugins/visualcomposer/plugin-
```

WP 6.2.2
PHP 8.2
Visual Composer 45.4.0

We tried:

- Deleting VC and reinstalling
- Recreating the same folder structure as above
- rolling back WP and PHP

None of these have fix the issue.